# history.push only updates the URL when using BrowserRouter in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I know this issue has been discussed before. But, somehow I cannot get it work in my application.

Normally, the navigation works fine between components. However, history.push only changes the url but does not update the content. For example, in the Login page, I want to navigate user to Home page if already logged in. But, the code only updates the url. Any ideas?

```
const Login = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (authenticationService.currentUserValue != null) {
            history.push('/home');
        }
    }, [])

    //other code
}
```

In index.js, I have the following

```
<BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl} history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
</BrowserRouter >,
```

In app.js, I have:

```
<Layout>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={withRouter(Home)} />
        <Route exact path='/home' component={withRouter(Home)} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/register' component={withRouter(Register)} />
    </Switch>
</Layout>
```

Comment: Try rendering your App component as a default Route. Also you don't need to use withRouter with components

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for the comment. Could you please help me understand what does it mean `rendering your App component as a default Route`?

Comment: <Route component={App}/>

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri this crashes the page.

Comment: changing `BrowserRouter` to `Router` solves the problem. But, what if I want to use `BrowserRouter`? Or should I?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your case is that you are using a custom history with BrowserRouter which isn't correct. BrowserRouter uses its own history and you must use that to change pages

```
const Login = ({history}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (authenticationService.currentUserValue != null) {
            history.push('/home');
        }
    }, [])

    //other code
}
```

If you have used custom history for a reason, then you need to use `Router` with a custom history prop

```
<Router basename={baseUrl} history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
</Router >
```